# Transformation logic for import entities from an external repository to a domain entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have an entity in my domain called 'Service.' For simplicity, let's assume it has just two value objects:

ServiceId (uuid)
ClientId (uuid)

I can access this entity through its own repository ('ServiceRepository').

My application needs to import services from an external source, but the fields in the external source require some transformation before I can save them using the 'ServiceRepository.' I receive these two fields from the external source:

ExternalServiceId (int)
ClientCode (string)

Before I can save these external services, I need to generate a ServiceId and find the ClientId for the ClientCode.

So, my approach is the following:

- Create two different entities with their repositories: 'Service' and 'ExternalService.'
- Create a use case which:

  1. Gets the services from the 'ExternalService' repository
  2. Use a service for transform the data from the ExternalService so I can save it using the 'ServiceRepository'

My question is if this would be the best approach because I will be duplicating the entity 'Service' and the repository. Is there any option for avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the domain layer must indicate your core business model and rules. Any other interaction with your domain is the Application layer's concern. Note that it's the ACL layer's job to retrieve data from an external service and convert data to contracts that the Application layer defines.

Here's a list of notes that you should apply to your design to prevent it from becoming a mess when you are communicating with external services:

- Do not pollute your domain with the domain model of external services. All the communications must go through the Application layer. Sometimes it's handling or publishing events (messaging between microservices or bounded contexts), and sometimes it's calling an ACL layer method to process a use case. So defining the ExternalService entity in your domain is wrong.
- To use external services, you should create an ACL layer around those services to prevent your application from getting tightly coupled with the external services. So your domain model must know nothing of converting or retrieving data from external services. The ACL layer pattern is one of the strategic patterns used in domain-driven design context mapping.
- Your application layer should define the interfaces it needs for the external services. To do that, put all the interfaces you need to use in the Application layer (probably in the Application contracts) and implement them in the ACL layer.

**Edit:**

If I got this right, I think you are duplicating data between multiple microservices. it's a common thing to do in microservice architecture.
You can define correspondent identity properties in your Service Entity to map the external service in your domain.
It's not bad to put tracking identities in your domain model to relate to external services. So you can put ExternalServiceId and ClientCode into your ServiceEntity. And with those identities, you can make sure that duplicate services won't get created in your database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm iterating on the initial approach, and I've decided to have only the Service entity in my domain, as you suggested. I will also have just one Repository with two implementations: the external (which will handle the transformation required to return a Service entity that works with my domain) and the local. The only issue I'm having is with the IDs of the external Service. I can assign a UUID "on the fly" to the entities loaded from the external service, but I'm not sure about how to push any changes to that external service because the IDs won't match anymore.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't define a repository for external services. Repositories are meaningless outside of the domain boundary. It means repositories are a part of the ubiquitous language of your domain. Put all conversions and retrieving data in the ACL interface.  
For the mapping issue, I will edit my answer to respond to that.

Comment: Actually, these external services come from an old app in our company, making them more of a legacy persistence layer than a 3rd party service. Additionally, I've found that I can convert integers (up to 128 bits, which is more than I actually need) to UUIDs. So, in the end, I'll treat this as a repository, converting the integer IDs to UUIDs so that my domain can work with this old repository while I migrate all these entities to the new one. Thank you very much for your help and the clarification of so many concepts!

Comment: Do not confuse the Repository pattern (which is an OOP software engineering pattern) with the DDD concept of Repository, which is a class that behaves like an in-memory collection of domain objects.

Comment: @David Oh I mistook the entity with the actual services. But even in this case, the old legacy domain still counts as a good nominee for an ACL service.  I'm glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do not publish your infrastructure details

This is an hypothesis but it sounds like `code` is a *natural key* for client, whereas `id` the *surrogate key* used as a *primary key* in an RDBMS. The same apply to `ExternalClientId` versus `ClientId`. If that is true, you should consider hiding the ids from the domain layer, as it is specific to the infrastructure layer you are using. If you want to change the persistence schema, or move to NoSQL database, having published the id to the domain layer will be a problem because they are RDBMS and schema dependent concepts.

If you only publish the natural keys to the domain layer, the repository will do the translation for you and the implementation is extra simple:

```cs
namespace Domain.ServiceContext;
public class Service
{
  public int ExternalServiceId { get; init; }
  public string ClientCode { get; init; }
  // additional service properties
}
```

```cs
namespace Domain.ServiceContext;
public interface IServiceRepository
{
  void Import(Domain.ServiceContext.Service service);
}
```

```cs
namespace Infrastructure;
public class ServiceRepository : IServiceRepository
{
  private readonly AppDbContext database;

  /// <summary>
  /// Returns the client id from the code or throws exception if not found
  /// </summary>
  private Guid FindClientId(string code) => database.Clients
    .First(client => client.Code == code)
    .Select(client => client.Id);

  /// <summary>
  /// Insert a new service and maps the client code to id
  /// </summary>
  public void Import(Domain.ServiceContext.Service service)
  {
    database.Services.Add(new Infrastructure.Model.Service
    {
      ServiceId = Guid.NewGuid(),
      ClientId = FindClientId(service.ClientCode)
      ExternalServiceId  = service.ExternalServiceId,
      // map additional properties if needed
    });
    database.SaveChanges(); // INSERT statement
  }
}
```